# Flutter TextField autofocus not working with SlideTransition

Tags: animation, textfield, navigator, autofocus

I have a screen with a single TextField (with autofocus: true) and a FlatButton.  When I do not use SlideTransition the TextField properly gets focus when the screen is accessed.  However, when I simply change the route to use SlideTransition for a nice animation to the second page, the TextField doesn't auto focus.

Example:
Autofocus works with:

`Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),);`

Autofocus does not work with (EnterExitRoute class from this [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/everything-you-need-to-know-about-flutter-page-route-transition-9ef5c1b32823)):

`Navigator.push(context,EnterExitRoute(exitPage: FirstPage(), enterPage: SecondPage()));`

How can I get the TextField to autofocus when using the animation to the SecondPage?

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this working using FocusNode.  I had tried FocusNode before posting.  The difference that got it working was to not have these lines inside initState like examples show:

```
  myFocusNode = FocusNode();
  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(myFocusNode);
```

initState wasn't getting called.  I am using StatefulWidget.  I'm not sure why initState wasn't getting called.  Maybe someone could provide a reason?